# The specified deps.json does not exists in .NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am running the `add-migration` command in Blazor on .NET 6. The solution gets built successfully, but I am getting the following error   - how to fix it?

> The specified deps.json [C:\Users\User\Desktop\Application\BlazorWebApplication\BlazorWebApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\BlazorWebApp.deps.json] does not exist

Comment: You can't use EF on a browser. There are no databases in a browser It makes no sense adding migrations to the *client* project.

Comment: So can't we Use Entity Framework With Blazor wasm

Comment: There are no databases in a browser. What would you need an ORM for? Blazor WASM is an SPA just like React and Angular. These can't connect to any databases either. It's the backend services they use that connect to databases. If you create a hosted WebAsm project, the services in the host project can connect to databases and use ORMs

Comment: so you mean i have to use external api project for data access

Comment: This looks like a bug. Migrations should work in a Blazor project. Also, you *can* use EF Core in wasm. SQLite works just fine inside the browser on wasm, and I think the Azure Cosmos DB client can also connect from wasm since it just sends HTTP requests.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "You can't use EF on a browser." this is incorrect. Using EF on the client side (browser) is one of the new features of .NET 6 as bricelam has indicated.  https://youtu.be/kesUNeBZ1Os and https://youtu.be/2UPiKgHv8YE are good references.

Comment: @TysonGibby those *videos* and *future technology demos* (not references) don't say what you think they do. You need a database to begin with and the practical databases available on a browser are remote. The demos depend on a custom WASM SQLite client built just for last year's MVP Summit as a demonstration.

Comment: @TysonGibby the browser alternatives (IndexedDB, local storage) aren't relational databases and don't need an ORM to begin with. They're built to store and retrieve objects based on keys already. Chris Sainty's Blazored libraries provide access to Local and Session storage. There are several attempts to use IndexedDB too, but almost all of the NuGet packages seem to be abandoned. On the other hand, you can use [IndexedDB through JS interop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) directly

Comment: In fact, the BlazeOrbital demo you refer too uses IndexedDB as a file storage to store the SQLite data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SQLitePCL.raw is an active project that was not just created for .NET conf.  This is the GitHub https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw and this is the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3/2.1.3 . I don't see anywhere in the documentation or otherwise where IndexDB is in use for this project, this project is specifically designed to provide an alternative to the client local storage.

Comment: @TysonGibby that's not what's used there. You can't use a *Windows binary* in a browser. And IndexedDB is explicitly mentioned in the Blazor projects you linked to

Comment: @TysonGibby you linked to Jeremy Likness' video, which talks about [this project](https://github.com/JeremyLikness/MvpSummitTaskList) that was presented to the MVP Summit last year. That's a demo, not production code or a supported library.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .NET 6 WASM is not a "Windows binary". It is Web Assemblies; which are compiled dlls for the web browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the error "The specified deps.json \[\] does not exist" for a .NET 6 Web Assembly app using EF and SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74948605/how-do-i-fix-the-error-the-specified-deps-json-does-not-exist-for-a-net-6)