# How do I fix the error "The specified deps.json [] does not exist" for a .NET 6 Web Assembly app using EF and SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I am building a NET 6 Blazor Web Assembly application using Entity Framework and SQLite. When I attempt to add the initial migration to the database, I get the error `"The specified deps.json [C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\bin\Debug\net6.0\ThePlayer.Client.deps.json] does not exist"`

I have the following references in my client (WASM) project:

```
  <ItemGroup>    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.12" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This is the github repo with the all the code: https://github.com/tysongibby/ThePlayer

Getting the following warnings in the output when I rebuild the project:

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ThePlayer.Shared, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Server\ThePlayer.Server.csproj (in 43 ms).
Restored C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\ThePlayer.Client.csproj (in 44 ms).
Restored C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Shared\ThePlayer.Shared.csproj (in 43 ms).
1>ThePlayer.Shared -> C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Shared\bin\Debug\net6.0\ThePlayer.Shared.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ThePlayer.Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning : Found a native function (sqlite3_config) with varargs in e_sqlite3. Calling such functions is not supported, and will fail at runtime. Managed DllImports: 
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_config_none(System.Int32) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_config_int(System.Int32, System.Int32) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_config_int_arm64cc(System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_config_log(System.Int32, System.IntPtr, SQLitePCL.hook_handle) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_config_log_arm64cc(System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, SQLitePCL.hook_handle) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning : Found a native function (sqlite3_db_config) with varargs in e_sqlite3. Calling such functions is not supported, and will fail at runtime. Managed DllImports: 
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_db_config_charptr(SQLitePCL.sqlite3, System.Int32, System.Byte*) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_db_config_charptr_arm64cc(SQLitePCL.sqlite3, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Byte*) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_db_config_int_outint(SQLitePCL.sqlite3, System.Int32, System.Int32, System.Int32*) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_db_config_int_outint_arm64cc(SQLitePCL.sqlite3, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.Int32*) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_db_config_intptr_int_int(SQLitePCL.sqlite3, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.Int32) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(244,5): warning :     System.Int32 sqlite3_db_config_intptr_int_int_arm64cc(SQLitePCL.sqlite3, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.Int32) (in [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3] SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3+NativeMethods)
2>Compiling native assets with emcc. This may take a while ...
2>[1/3] pinvoke.c -> pinvoke.o [took 0.38s]
2>[2/3] corebindings.c -> corebindings.o [took 0.46s]
2>[3/3] driver.c -> driver.o [took 0.56s]
2>Linking with emcc. This may take a while ...
2> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\bin\wasm-ld.exe" -o C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\dotnet.wasm C:\Users\tyson.LAPPY9000\.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3\2.1.3\buildTransitive\net6.0\..\..\runtimes\browser-wasm\nativeassets\net6.0\e_sqlite3.a C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\pinvoke.o C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\driver.o C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\corebindings.o "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libicui18n.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libicuuc.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmono-component-debugger-static.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmono-component-diagnostics_tracing-stub-static.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmono-component-hot_reload-static.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmono-ee-interp.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmono-icall-table.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmono-ilgen.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmono-profiler-aot.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libmonosgen-2.0.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\6.0.12\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\libSystem.Native.a" "-LC:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libgl.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libal.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libhtml5.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libc.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libcompiler_rt.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libc++.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libc++abi.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libdlmalloc.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libc_rt_wasm.a" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten\libsockets.a" -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-cxx-exceptions -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr --allow-undefined --export putchar --export stackSave --export stackRestore --export stackAlloc --export __wasm_call_ctors --export __errno_location --export malloc --export free --export __cxa_is_pointer_type --export __cxa_can_catch --export setThrew --export _get_tzname --export _get_daylight --export _get_timezone --export memalign --export memset --export emscripten_main_thread_process_queued_calls --export ntohs --export htons --export htonl --export-if-defined=__start_em_asm --export-if-defined=__stop_em_asm --export-table -z stack-size=5242880 --initial-memory=536870912 --no-entry --max-memory=2147483648 --global-base=1024
2> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\bin\wasm-emscripten-finalize" --minimize-wasm-changes -g --dyncalls-i64 --dwarf C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\dotnet.wasm -o C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\dotnet.wasm --detect-features
2> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Node.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\bin\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\emscripten\src\compiler.js" C:\Users\TYSON~1.LAP\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppxf580an.txt
2> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Sdk.win-x64\6.0.12\tools\bin\llvm-objcopy.exe" C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\dotnet.wasm C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\wasm\for-build\dotnet.wasm --remove-section=producers
2>Optimizing dotnet.wasm ...
2>ThePlayer.Client -> C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\bin\Debug\net6.0\ThePlayer.Client.dll
2>ThePlayer.Client (Blazor output) -> C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Client\bin\Debug\net6.0\wwwroot
2>Done building project "ThePlayer.Client.csproj".
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ThePlayer.Server, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>ThePlayer.Server -> C:\git\ThePlayer\ThePlayer\Server\bin\Debug\net6.0\ThePlayer.Server.dll
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:18.020 ==========
```

Comment: Your git repo references code from outside of the repo. The missing project blocks anyone from reproducing your issue.

Comment: @stefan.seeland Thanks for looking over my question and for noticing that issue. I have updated the code to reference the necessary nuget package now instead of the nuget project. It will work for reproducing the issue now.

Comment: Opened an issue for this with the author at the github repo https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/533

Comment: SQLLitePCL.raw directed me to open an issue with the EntityFramework team on their GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket with the Entity Framework team and they provided this work-around for the issue:

The workaround is to create a separate console application project in the solution. This project is used only to enable the EF tools to create an appropriate context instance. The project needs to reference the project containing your DbContext and the EF Core database provider you are using. For example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="6.0.12" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\ThePlayer\Shared\ThePlayer.Shared.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The console application needs to have an `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using ThePlayer.Shared.Data.Context;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

public class ContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ThePlayerContext>
{
    public ThePlayerContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) 
        => new(null, new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ThePlayerContext>().UseSqlite(args[0]).Options);
}
```

This can then be used to generate migrations from the command line. For example:

```
PS C:\local\code\repros\ThePlayer-master\ThePlayer-master\ConsoleApp1> dotnet ef migrations add One --project ..\ThePlayer\Shared\ThePlayer.Shared.csproj -- "DataSource=ThePlayer.db"
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'
PS C:\local\code\repros\ThePlayer-master\ThePlayer-master\ConsoleApp1>
```

source: [How do generate migrations for an Blazor WASM](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4230)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful too if using UNC paths in your project (e.g. using a VM and sharing access to your desktop, etc). For me, the deps.json file existed but Visual Studio (though it could build and run the application) could not access the UNC path to get to the .deps file.

Moving my project to a local drive fixed the problem.

> PM> Add-Migration initial
> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> The specified deps.json [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\Repos\EFCore\PublisherConsole\bin\Debug\net6.0\PublisherConsole.deps.json] does not exist

Answer (score -1):

If you still have an error then remove the parameters and pass the database connection string right away. It helped me

```
public DB CreateDbContext(string[] args)
                => new DB(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DB>().UseSqlServer("server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=TodoDB;Integrated Security=true").Options);
```

The error I had

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Todo_List.EntityFrameworkMigration.Program.ContextFactory.CreateDbContext(String[] args) in D:\Repos\Todo_List.EntityFrameworkMigration\Program.cs:line 17
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContextFromFactory(Type factory, Type contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_2.<FindContextTypes>b__9()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: But that totally defeats the purpose of a config file. This is not a fix.